# Can I view how many times a user has logged into my site in EE?

Tags: add-on

All I can see is when they registered and when they last logged in. Can I get more detail - for example, how many times they have logged in, the time they spent on the site etc. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can see to do this would be to catch a successful login and process a tracking cookie or session to capture the time until they logout. You would have to do something that didn't clash with EE's variables, but something like:

```
$_SESSION['loginTime'] = new DateTime(date('y-m-d h:m:s'));
```

You would need to either write an addon or enable PHP though. Once they log out, you could capture the time and log the difference.

Comment: The catch is that most people (like me) never logout.......

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know of a way to capture that. You might try doing something like `window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {  };` and trigger something the server can catch.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish acquiring the metrics like your after, I wrote an extension and accessory for a client that writes, login-timestamp, sessionid & user_id to a table, I also do logout as well, but most people don't usually logout making it tough to actually measure time on site. The accessory is a dashboard for the data.